# Modo desarrollador desabilitado W11

Tags: flutter, vscode, windows11

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podria decirme poque me sale desabilitado el modo desarrollador en W11 PRO, no tengo manera de poder activarlo.
Mi cuenta es administrador, no se que puede pasar y me estoy volviendo loco.
Tengo una aplicación en FLutter y cuando la ejecuto en windows me dice que ponga el siguiente comando '

```
Exception: Building with plugins requires symlink support.

Please enable Developer Mode in your system settings. Run
  start ms-settings:developers
to open settings.
```

Pero luego no puedo hacer nada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que indica el mensaje es para abrir la configuración de desarrollo, pero usa PowerShell como administrador:

```
start ms-settings:developer
```

Si no tienes habilitado el modo desarrollador usa PowerShell como administrador, definiendo los siguientes comando:

```
Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense -Online
sc config debugregsvc start=auto
Start-Service -Name DebugRegsvc
```

Comment: No funciona, me arroja el error: Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense : No se encuentra ningún parámetro que coincida con el nombre del parámetro 'Online'.

Comment: @jose22 Hola, es muy importante usar PowerShell como administrador de tu pc

Comment: Si, si lo ejecuto como administrador

Answer (score 1):

Puedes seguir estos pasos:

1. Entra a configuración
2. Y luego ve a sistema
3. Dentro debe estar una opción que dice para programadores
4. Ahí puedes habilitar el modo desarrollador en W11 PRO